# Caught ValueError while rendering: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: django, django-models

im trying to pass a generated "choices" to my model field, please where is the problem?

```
#models.py
...

def quantity_total():
        for x in range(0,100): return "(" + str(x) + "," + str(x) + "),"

QUANTITY = (quantity_total())

class Package(models.Model):
   ...
   ...
   quantity =  models.SmallIntegerField(choices=QUANTITY, max_length=3)
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) is supposed to be an iterable of 2-tuples, not a string.

```
def quantity_total():
        return ((x, str(x)) for x in xrange(100))
```

Comment: Also, it'd be an idea to kill the `()` when assigning to `QUANTITY`, since it's unnecessary and confusion.